# Who is more powerful?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, islamic-scholar

Ãsak
I have a question.
According to Islam, which person is more powerful.
One who has abundant knowledge or the one who has more strength.

Comment: Unless there's a clear statement making a comparison between both there's no possibility to compare them. Questions about "the best", "the worst", and comparative questions are hardly on-topic here as they usually attract subjective answers (check our [help] to see what's on-topic here and read [ask]). Note that none of the used tags seems fit to your post.

Answer (score -1):

As per Hazrat Ali RA, Power and wealth dont change person. It just reveal him. 
About knowledge- devil was one of the most knowledgeable during his good time.

So who is the most strongest? Hazrat Ali RA says, the most powerful is the one who has control on his anger.

Hazrat Ali "Loin of ALLAH" was about to kill a person during war and he spitted on HIM. HE moved back and allowed him to leave. The person got surprised and asked why YOU didnt kill me, then the Great Caliph said I was about to kill you for Allah but when you spit then i doubt my personal anger can be included in it.
The person converted to Islam